# regex: Separating words before and after colon

Tags: regex, unix, flex-lexer

In the line over here:

`Category Shoes brand:char[30];cost:float;years:int`

I'm trying to write two separate regex expressions: one to separate the label that would appear before the colon, and another to get the expression after the colon upto the next semicolon or end of line.

So far I've come up with

a.)  `[^:]+` for the first case

b.) `[\:...\;]` for the second case

My Flex files reads:

```
%%
[^:]+     { printf("\nLabel: %s\n",yytext); }
[\:...\;] { printf("\nType: %s\n",yytext); }
%%
```

However, the output is as follows:

```
Label: char
Category Shoes brand

Type: :

Label: char[30];cost

Type: :

Label: float;years

Type: :
```

Any input as to how I would go about solving this would be great.

EDIT:

Expected output:

```
    Label: brand

    Type: char[30]

    Label: cost

    Type: float

    Label: years

    Type: Float
```

Comment: Can you post the exact output you want to get?

Comment: I don't understand yet.  Why is the last 'type' Float (with a capitol F), and why are there more 'types' than 'labels'?

Comment: This is probably where you consider using a grammar as well as a scanner.  You can pick up labels with `[a-zA-Z0-9]+:` (note that it will include the colon); you can pick up other words (such as 'Category' and 'Shoes') with `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`; you can pick up types with `[^;]+;` (maybe escaping the semicolons, and noting that this will include the semicolons); and you can ignore spaces and newlines. Untested, of course.  Beware sequencing; you might need to list the regex for types before the regex for plain words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%%

[a-zA-Z0-9]+:   { printf("Label: <<%s>>\n", yytext); }
[a-zA-Z0-9]+    { printf("Word:  <<%s>>\n", yytext); }
[^:\;]+\;       { printf("Type:  <<%s>>\n", yytext); }
.               { printf("Skip:  <<%s>>\n", yytext); }

%%
```

Sample output (for your sample input):

```
Word:  <<Category>>
Skip:  << >>
Word:  <<Shoes>>
Skip:  << >>
Label: <<brand:>>
Type:  <<char[30];>>
Label: <<cost:>>
Type:  <<float;>>
Label: <<years:>>
Word:  <<int>>
```

Comment: Any good resources for Regex you'd trust? I've been half-assing it using the
 quickrefs.

Comment: Jeff Friedl's book [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://regex.info/) is arguably the best. (As it happens, I'm re-reading it at the moment.)  It doesn't specifically cover Flex, but if you understand what's in it, understanding Flex is not hard.

Answer (score 1):

Check [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns) for better understanding of flex patterns.
I believe the piece of code below do what you expected.(not tested)

```
%x INTYPE
h
[a-z]*`:` { printf("\nLabel: %s\n",yytext); BEGIN(INTYPE); }

<INTYPE>{
    ; { BEGIN(INITIAL); }
    [a-z"[""]"0-9]* {printf("\ntype: %s\n",yytext); } 
}
```